# How to get result with variable in where condition which was set using SET

Tags: mysql

I have problem in getting the result for below query:

```
SELECT setting_value FROM system_settings WHERE setting_key='hold_series' INTO @Current;
```

where 'setting_value' is a text data type and has the value as

```
50472949,15804527,13613881,13607299,16226328,15774405,14416070.

SELECT * from users where Id in (@Current) [and some left joins];
```

resulted only one record, I am sure I have all the records in users table.

If I use

```
SELECT * from users where Id in (50472949,15804527,13613881,13607299,16226328,15774405,14416070)
```

with left joins , it resulted with all 7 rows. :(

Please let me know what am I doing wrong...

Thanks, 
-Jyo

Comment: I got it solved by using the below condition

    AND CONCAT(',',@Current,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',Id,',%')

Hope this helps someone who encounters the same situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * from users where (FIND_IN_SET(id,@Current)>0)
```